# AWS General Purpose SSD Charges after reservation of ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Please let me aware about the charges of ssd while all ec2 instances is reserved, then why $0.10 per GB-month is deducting?

I have reserved c4.2xlarge and m4.xlarge instances but still charges are continuous deducted from bill the heavy charge only for this below:

**$0.10 per GB-month of General Purpose SSD (gp2) provisioned storage - US East (Northern Virginia)**

For the saving of  cost what can i do more? like above things are not happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that your situation is:

- You have purchase Reserved Instances for a `c4.2xlarge` and a `m4.xlarge` instance
- You are seeing charges for Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) SSD storage

This is normal behaviour.

A Reserved Instance is a pre-payment (either monthly or annual) for Amazon EC2 capacity. When running an EC2 instance that matches the Reserved Instances, there is no hourly charge because the Reserved Instance has pre-paid for that usage.

However, **the cost of Amazon EBS is not included with a Reserved Instance**. The cost of an EBS volume is additional to your Amazon EC2 costs. This applies for all types of EC2 instances, whether or not they are being charged as Reserved Instances and whether they are Running or Stopped.

Some options to further save money:

- Only create EBS disk volumes as large as necessary. You always pay for the *full* size of the volume, so unused space still costs money. You can always **modify** the volume to make it bigger in future.
- **Turn off instances** when they are not required, at least for any instances not covered by your Reserved Instance purchases
- If you are running additional instances, consider using **Spot Pricing** (but instances might be terminated if the spot price rises higher than your bid price)

Comment: Hi @PankajGupta if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: One more thing I want to know that, what is the mean of usage? Is not fix ? as I have attached two 50 GB and two 30 Gb so what would be the charges of one month? According to usage the cost increasing daily basis.

Comment: You mean my statement that "there is no hourly charge because the Reserved Instance has pre-paid for that usage"? It means that the RI pre-pays one hour of usage for the given instance type, for each hour of the year. Therefore, if you run an instance that matches the RI in a given hour, there is no charge for that hour (because you have already pre-paid for the instance via the RI payment). Think of it like a water tap that is always running - you prepay for the water and then you can choose to drink the water, or not drink it. Either way the water goes away and is not kept for the next hour.

Comment: @PankajGupta the "usage" charge for EBS volumes appears to be increasing daily because you don't pay for the entire month unless you keep the volume for the entire month. You can delete or replace the volumes at any time. For each day the volumes exist, you are billed for one more day of usage, and with EBS, "usage" refers to the disk space allocated for your use, regardless of how much data is stored on it.  If you provision an EBS volume for one day, then destroy it, your entire cost would be approximately the monthly EBS volume "Gigabit-month" rate ÷ 30.  This is billed by the hour.